# SQL Server get updated columns in trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[tr_test]
ON [dbo].[customers]
for insert, update, delete
as
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT  = 0)  return
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED I JOIN DELETED D
    ON I.id_no = D.id_no
        AND EXISTS (SELECT I.*
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT D.*)
```

The trigger returns the join and obviously includes all the table's columns, even those that didn't change.

Is it possible to filter out unchanged columns and thus return only those columns that have actually changed?

Comment: Your logic in the select statement seems flawed if I'm reading it right. It would seem that if a row is inserted it won't exist in _deleted_ and will be filtered out by the join; if a row is updated it will exist in both _inserted_ and _deleted_ but will be removed from the set by the exists predicate; and if a row is deleted it won't exist in _inserted_ and will be filtered out by the join. So the select can't return any rows ever?

Comment: In any case you can use [UPDATED()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) AND [COLUMNS_UPDATED()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) to check if one or more (in the latter case) column(s) has changed. As far as I know you can't get a list of changed columns though so you would have to test each column you are interested in. But my knowledge concerning triggers is a bit limited.

Comment: @jpw those functions only tell you if the column was part of the SET list. They don't tell you if the column value actually changed as a result.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Are you sure about that? The documentation for`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`seem to suggest that it indeed sets a flag if the column was updated, and the first example given (using an `after update`trigger) seem to confirm this, although it does fire for `set value=value`too, even though the value never changes. Or maybe I'm completely misinterpreting the documentation and example code.

Comment: @jpw That's my point. If you say `SET value = value` or `SET value = <same value as it was before>`, both `UPDATE()` and `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` will reflect that column. So as I said, that doesn't tell you whether the value has actually changed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Got it.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this-

```html
CREATE trigger [dbo].[tr_test]
ON [dbo].[Grades]
for insert, update, delete
as
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT  = 0)  return
    SET NOCOUNT ON
   
create tablae #inserted (...)
  insert into #inserted
   SELECT *  
    from INSERTED
create tablae #deleted (...)
     insert into #deleted
    SELECT *  
    from deleted
```

then use this script

```html
 SELECT *
        FROM #inserted
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from #deleted)
```

Comment: I would like to know why this answer not useful

Comment: The trigger doesn't return records